# use ubuntu app on raspberry

Tags: bluetooth

i want send file via raspberry pi to other phone via obex object push profile ...

in raspberry pi i can use `ussp-push` but this app is very very slow

i test this app in `ubuntu` and `raspberry raspbian` and same result (transfer speed very slow)

i test `bluetooth-sendto` app in terminal on `ubuntu` and speed is great

so i want to use `bluetooth-sendto` on `raspberry` to send file ...

i dont want graphical part and i want only use this on terminal ...

how i can compile and use `bluetooth-sendto` on rapsberry ?